# How can I exclude beans from certain contexts in Spring?

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I have a project that mixes Spring Batch with Spring Web. It's primarily a Spring Batch project that runs jobs, but we've got a few REST endpoints on there, and the [Spring Batch Admin Manager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/tree/master/spring-batch-admin-manager) module as well. Our base project has its own (primary) application context, but the Admin Manager project we've included in the POM effectively creates its own context as well.

One of my classes is a `@RestController` which means it automatically gets instantiated by both contexts. This controller has a couple of `@Autowired` dependencies, which is fine when the first context runs because it finds them all. But when the second context runs, it fails to find those dependencies and so the app fails to launch properly.

But because this second context is created automatically, behind the scenes, from that aforementioned Sping Batch Admin Manager project, I don't really have control over it. Is there some way I can manually specify in my `@RestController` that it should be excluded from all but my primary context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the @Conditional annotations

E.g. `@ConditionalOnClass` or `@ConditionalOnMissingClass` or `@ConditionalOnBean` or `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`

So your controller just checks whether there is classes/beans which is required to run the endpoint

Read more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html)